# How to get CSS grid to span across columns into the next row?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am building a site, and am trying to create a page where I can talk about some of the coding projects I have done.  I have used grids for the majority of my site, and would like to keep it consistent throughout but I can't seem to find a way to have a box span to the end of its column, and then and then continue into the next row starting the first column.  I have looked through the css documentation, and also through stack overflow, and am a little surprised this question hasn't been raised before.  My grid is made up of 3 rows and 4 columns, so its 12 total boxes.  I want to start in the first row, third column and span the rest of the column, and then continue into the second row, and starting with the first column span all the way until the end, and then continue into the third row and span the first two columns.  The reason I want to do this is that boxes 1 and 2, and 11 and 12 will contain images, and the big area I am trying to create will contain text, so the text will wrap nicely around the images.  If you could help me out, or suggest another way in which this can be done I would be appreciative. [What I am trying to accomplish, I want to put one block of text in the area that starts with 3 and ends with 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXRuE.png)

Comment: What have you got so far? Post your html and css. See: [mcve]

Comment: there is 2 links that you read (again) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ & https://gridbyexample.com/ while setting a snippet (HTML & CSS)  to show us your issue. grid-row is to be used, else set a grid-template-area and grid-area